# Colorbox JQuery, colorbox not showing or doubling

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I have a problem with colorbox:

I have a page that would receive part of its content by AJAX. Now within that ajax retrieved content there are Colorbox links as well. Now these links don´t work, or rather said the first click would not work (but would lead to the link within the browser except the link within a colorbox), now after having the first click (which would not work as described before), hitting the back button of the browser all further links would display - as wanted - in a colorbox.

I tried several browsers with all having the same result. So I thought - especially since after having gone wrong once then working correctly - this could probably be a problem of having the colorbox library not in the cache. 
So I tried to add this line of code (except for being on the main page anyway) within the ajax retrieved content

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cbDetails").colorbox();
}
</script>
```

which leads to the error explained above not happening anymore but rather doubling and trippling the colorbox layers so to say, which means, after having hit 2 different colorbox links one would need 2 clicks to close the colorbox, after having hit 3 different colorboxes one would need 3 clicks to close those third colorbox and so on...

---

As I was asked to do so, here is the relevant code:

Now that is the main page including that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var currentTime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cbDetails").colorbox();
});
</script>
```

as well as in the  body then that:

```
echo '<a href=\'cb.script.php?do=order&id='.$check['id'].'&prod='.$check['prod'].'\' class="cbDetails"><button style="width:60px;" class="order" title="Ordern">Ordern</button></a>';
```

which would create work out good. But if I have the second part, so that one:

```
echo '<a href=\'cb.script.php?do=order&id='.$check['id'].'&prod='.$check['prod'].'\' class="cbDetails"><button style="width:60px;" class="order" title="Ordern">Ordern</button></a>';
```

being placed on the same page by AJAX it would not work any more (while having that AJAX is crucial to me).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're using a class to select, `$(".cbDetails").colorbox();` would apply to all elements with that class and open up a lot of windows as you're describing.  Try to target your clicks more specifically with id's or `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cbDetails").on("click", function()
    {$(this).colorbox();});
});
```

Comment: Tried that (used id instead), but would not help. Code coming gimme a few mins to copy and paste (will be pasted to my main question).

Comment: shouldn't .colorbox() be called by a button click and not in document ready?

Comment: Stefan I thought it would modify all links with the class cbDetails to be opened in a colorbox after the html page was loaded...

Comment: tried the code posted above, Stefan, but that would make colorbox not working at all on my page.